# How to overwrite and print the values in console in java

Tags: java

Here is one while loop that will iterate 11 times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int count=0;
        while(count<=10){       
            System.out.print(count);
            count++;
        }   
    }
```

& the output will be definitely : `012345678910`

But I want to display the same output in such a way that every iteration will overwrite the previous value while printing the value on console.

**Here's the restriction is : We can not use file.**

clearing the console on every iteration can be one of the ways, is there anything left we can do?

Comment: Apologies! Updated to 11.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\r` which returns to the start of a line: `System.out.print("\r" + count);` should work.

Comment: Apologies if I've misunderstood you... How do you mean?

Comment: @S.Das this should work, but bear in mind, it only works on command line and NOT on eclipse or other IDEs

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is you have to pad spaces to get rid of old output.

Comment: I've thried that and does not work in Windows. I don't know if it should work in Linux or Mac